Selecting Indices for the Riemann Tensor
How do I know when computing the Riemann Tensor (in two dimensional) which indices to select? Consider the Riemann Tensor $R^a_{bcd}$ how do I know what values to take for $a$?
As an example, consider the 2 sphere with $g_{ij}= r^2 , r^2 \sin^2\theta $ in the coordinate frame $(\theta , \phi )$.
In the solution to the problem, I have seen that $R^\phi_{\theta\theta\phi}$ is selected but could I also choose for example to take $R^\theta_{\theta\phi\theta}$ or $R^\theta_{\phi\phi\theta}$ or $R^\phi_{\theta\phi\theta}$. Is there any way of deciding how do decide the upper index of the Riemann Tensor and does it matter which one I select or can I just pick any indices at random?
Thank you for your help

In general, when computing the Riemann tensor, you'll want to know all possible combinations of indices.
In two dimensions specifically, the symmetries of the Riemann tensor force it to have only one independent component. So, if you compute any non-vanishing component you will automatically know all the $2^4 = 16$ components of the tensor.
To be more specific, in two dimensions we have (if I'm not mistaken)
$$R_{abcd} = \frac{R}{2}(g_{ac}g_{bd} - g_{a d}g_{b c}),$$
where $R$ is the Ricci scalar, and then you can just lift one index to get to the tensor you want.

Thank you but I still don't understand how to select the one that I need? like how would I know which to lift?

@missyclarke1998 Which particular component you'll need will probably depend on the specific problem you're working out. Since you didn't detail anything, I assumed you just wanted to know about the Riemann tensor in general

@missyclarke1998 Due to skew-symmetry in first two indices, we only need to know $R_{12cd}$. Due to skew-symmetry in the last two indices, we only need to know $R_{1212}=R_{2121}$, i.e $R_{\theta\phi\theta\phi}=R_{\phi\theta\phi\theta}$. If you then want the upper index version, just carry out the appropriate sum (but really I’d rather stick to the lowered version).
